# How do you pass a JSON string from an AJAX call to a .Net Core controller action?

Tags: javascript, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I've read several examples of this and just can't get it to work. I'm trying to pass json data to a .Net Core controller action and the value is always null inside my action method. I've tried multiple variations of what I have here and nothing seems to work. In this example I have set places to a literal to be sure I'm trying to pass valid JSON.

Javascript:

```
function GetRatedPlaces(places) {
            places = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
            var placesJson = JSON.stringify(places);
            console.log(placesJson);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRatedPlaces", "Home")',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: placesJson,
                cache: false,
                success: function (result) {
                    // Handle the response from the controller
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller Action:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetRatedPlaces([FromBody] string places)
        {
            // Deserialize places here.

            return Ok();
        }
```

Comment: Is your places a model ?

Comment: Typically, the problem will be with either the AJAX code or the C# code. It's usually helpful to isolate the problem. Look at the HTTP `POST` request. Does the HTTP request look correct? Then the problem is likely to be on the server side. If not, the problem is likely to be with the AJAX. Once you've isolated the problem, please edit the question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @QingGuo I was attempting to do this with just a string. No model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First way:**
try to create a model:

```
public class Places
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}
```

then:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetRatedPlaces([FromBody]Places places)
{
    // Deserialize places here.

    return Ok();
}
```

result:
[image]

**Second way:**
You can try the below code:

```
function GetRatedPlaces(places) {
            places = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
            var placesJson = JSON.stringify(places);
            console.log(placesJson);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetRatedPlaces", "Home")',
               
                data: places,
                
                success: function (result) {
                    // Handle the response from the controller
                }
            });
        }
```

The action set the parameters to bind data:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetRatedPlaces( string name,int age,string city)
{
    // Deserialize places here.

    return Ok();
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks @qingguo.

Comment: Hi @B. Jones, You are welcome:)  any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Qing Guo That took care of it. I'm still sorting out a few details, but that explanation really helped.