# ModelPage function is receiving null parameters; how to remedy this?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm currently learning how to pass values to a Post method using AJAX to no avail; this is in .NET Core 6 Razor Pages and here are the codes.

Front end:

```
function calculateSalary() {

    var dropdown = document.getElementById("industryDropdown");
    var selectedOption = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex];

    var industryrange1, industryrange2;

    industryrange1 = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-range1');
    industryrange2 = selectedOption.getAttribute('data-range2');

    var range1Value = String(industryrange1);
    var range2Value = String(industryrange2);

    console.log(range1Value);
    console.log(range2Value);

    try {


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()},
            url: '/Index?handler=Calculate', // Replace with the actual path to your Razor Page method
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ range1: range1Value, range2: range2Value }),
       
            success: function (result) {
                // Update the value of the textbox with the result
                console.log(result);
                $('#Message').val(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Error:', error);
            }
        });

    }

    catch (error) {

        console.error(error);
    }

}
```

When a button is clicked, this AJAX method passes 2 values to a function in the Model page. The Model function in question is as follows:

```
public IActionResult OnPostCalculate([FromBody] string range1, [FromBody] string range2)
{


    var monthly_credit = employeeRepository.GetContribution(range1, range2);

    foreach (var credit in monthly_credit)
    {
        Message = $"SSS Contribution = {credit}";
    }

    return new JsonResult(Message);


}
```

Ideally, this function will pass the received values from AJAX and send it to another function that handles data retrieval from an SQL table, put the value in the string Message variable, and have that string be displayed in a textbox in the website.

The SQL function code is as follows:

```
public IEnumerable<SSS> GetContribution([FromBody] string range1, [FromBody] string range2)
{
    double parsedRange1 = double.Parse(range1);
    double parsedRange2 = double.Parse(range2);

    
    //SQL code that returns values from tables
}
```

**Problem and Solutions I've tried**

The reason I didn't include the SQL code is because the parameters being received by the model and SQL functions are null. I found during debugging that:

- there are no Javascript errors in website console
- the data being sent by AJAX has value and is correct; the console.log commands and Network tab under Payload Request even displays them
- the null exception is triggered by the SQL function and not the previous ones; somehow range1 and range2 values in AJAX become null after being sent

I've tried running the code with and without [FromBody] and JSON.stringify, put [HttpPost] on the model function and still the same error.

Any help on how to remedy this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                    $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                   },
            url: '/Index?handler=Calculate', // Replace with the actual path to your Razor Page method
           
            data: { range1: range1Value, range2: range2Value },
       
            success: function (result) {
                // Update the value of the textbox with the result
                console.log(result);
                $('#Message').val(result);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('Error:', error);
            }
        });
```

Then:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult OnPostCalculate( string range1,  string range2)
{
...}
```

In program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
```

In the view add:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

Comment: I followed the first two (modifying AJAX and the [FromBody]) and it worked! May I ask how that helped? Did the content type and JSON type made it so that the functions can't read JSON?

Comment: @N.Tanaka  ,yes , somewhat you are right,  most because model binding cannot bind the json data to the range1,range2.

Comment: @N.Tanaka , you can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256467/how-do-you-pass-a-json-string-from-an-ajax-call-to-a-net-core-controller-action/77256566#77256566)  to know more.

Comment: Appreciate the help, thank you!